# What's the ideal ES target for an npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-package

I think there are mostly 2 cases here:

- Packages that run exclusively in the browser (i.e. front-end libraries)
- Packages that may run in Node (i.e. general JS libraries, back-end libraries, build tools)

I would say that the former can target the latest ES spec, as it should be transpiled to whatever ES target the end product uses. Therefore using the highest possible ES has no downside for those who can afford it, i.e. avoiding bundling an ES5 dependency with unnecessary transpilations in a project that targets ES7 anyway.

The modules which are expected to run in Node should target ES that is supported by whatever is deemed the minimum required Node version.

Am I getting this right or are there some pitfalls and it's universally better to use a lower target like ES5?

Comment: I know that there are cases where a package would be used outside of npm, i.e. including React on a webpage. That is not a concern, a separate browser bundle for use outside npm can be generated alongside.